# Is it possible to bring the tab content after the a tag to maintain my html structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have react tabs code working perfectly but I need to change the html structure to match the below one. Is it possible to bring the tab content after the `<a>` tag to maintain my html structure?

https://jsfiddle.net/9e767txs/9/

```or-tag-here
<div className="sports-tab-container">
  <ul>
    <li role="presentation" className="sports-setup-ico first-time-active ft-active-tab">
      <a href="javascript:;" className="sports-tab-header">
        <h2>sports player</h2>
        <p className="sports-subtitle">Days 1 and 2</p>
      </a>
      <div className="sports-tab-content">
        <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" className="sports-invest-ico">
      <a href="javascript:;" className="sports-tab-header">
        <h2>car selling</h2>
        <p className="sports-subtitle">Approx. Day 3</p>
      </a>
      <div className="sports-tab-content">
        <p className="sports-large-text ft-day1 ft-day2">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: React generates the HTML for the most part, including the `<a>` elements. Why do you care what the exact structure is, as long as it's meaningful and renders correctly?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your reply, I have a protype which is written in html, css nd jquery...I am trying to match it..so that i can take those css and add it it my code...thats the reason i am trying to change the html structure in my fiddle...

Comment: I think it would be easier to change your CSS. Otherwise you'll probably have to change how React works

Comment: @ADyson can you tell me how to change in react...sinc eI am not allowed to touch css :(

Comment: not off the top of my head. I don't know that much about React specifically. You would have to read the documentation and see if there's anything which allows you to specify the HTML elements used or their positioning. But I doubt there is, since the whole purpose of these frameworks is to abstract away the job of generating repetitive HTML. More likely you would have to modify the source code of React, which really defeats the point of using it. Perhaps you should ask the person who maintains the CSS whether they can make you a new version to suit React's HTML.

Comment: @ADyson hey but the content of html structure should be different, so we should generate html right

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Judging from your fiddle, React generates at least some of the HTML for you, and certainly positions it for you, although looking again it does seem like some of it might be changeable by altering the structure of your React classes and what they output, so maybe you could change it sufficiently. maybe not, depends on the limitations of the framework. I'm not a React expert, like I said, so, assuming you _really_ can't update your CSS to suit the new HTML (which would be easier), then maybe you just need to play with the fiddle a bit and see what's possible.

Comment: _"can you tell me how to change in react...since I am not allowed to touch css"_ - why would you not be allowed to touch the CSS, if all that exists so far is a prototype anyway? And if "they" won't let you touch the CSS (fearing you might mess it up, or what?) - then they would rather let you make modifications to a 3d-party framework ...?

Answer (score 0):

From your title, this is how I would structure the React code.  I have left out all of the styling information.  Assuming you will get a list of data.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const data = [
  { heading: 'sports player',
    subtitle: 'Days 1 and 2',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'
  },
  { heading: 'car selling',
    subtitle: 'Approx. Day 3<',
    content: 'It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when'}
]

const Heading = ({heading, subtitle}) => {
  return(
    <a>
      <h2>{heading}</h2>
      <p>{subtitle}</p>
    </a>
    )
}

const Content = ({content}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
    )
}
const Sports = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      { data.map(element => {
        return(
          <li>
            <Heading heading={element.heading} subtitle={element.subtitle}/>
            <Content content={element.content} />
          </li>
          )
      })}
    </ul>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sports data={data} />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

[See on CodePen](http://codepen.io/JTKirk/pen/dOPpev/)

Comment: I added a new link to CodePen.